# eliminate duplicates based on status conditions

Tags: mysql

I have a table employee with fields empid,status,name. they are multiple record with same emp ids.Conditions to be applied are as follows:

1. Obtain a single record for each employee id
2. IF fail status exists eliminate the record unless they have a status of withhold or withdrawn or both.

Table Struture:

```
empid      name      status
1          p1        fail
2          p2        pass
2          p2        fail
3          p3        pass
4          p4        pass
4          p4        onhold
5          p5        fail
5          p5        withheld
5          p5        withdrawn
6          p6        fail
6          p6        withheld
6          p6        withdrawn
6          p6        onhold
7          p7        fail
7          p7        withheld
8          p8        fail
8          p8        withdrawn
9          p9        fail
9          p9        withdrawn
9          p9        onhold
10         p10       pass
10         p10       onhold
10         p10       withdrawn
11         p11       waiting
11         p11       disburse
11         p11       withdrawn
12         p12       disburse
12         p12       fail
```

Result should look like:

```
empid      name
3          p3
4          p4
5          p5  
6          p6
7          p7
8          p8
9          p9
10         p10
11         p11
```

I am new to MYSQL. Any help would be appreciated.Thanks

Comment: Why is `empid = 1, name = 'p1'` in the results. I don't see the withhold or withdrawn status for that empid

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct empid, name from employee where status <> 'fail'
```

Comment: so much for unless they have a status of withhold or withdrawn or both

Comment: Need to get emp record if status fail exists with combination of withheld,withdrawn or both

Comment: @PragmaR that's different than your results. Which are both different than your description.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT empid, name FROM employee WHERE status != 'fail'
```

**DISTINCT** keyword is used to get the unique values. So here it will return unique employee ids with status except 'fail'

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct(I hope) query for what you were asking. This is how it works:
It rates each status with an integer value. Passes get a 0, fails get 1 and anything else gets a 2. The query groups by empid and aggretates the maximum of these 3 possible values.
So, if the max is a 0 that means that everything is a pass, so we want it in.
If the max is a 1 it means there are only passes and fails, so we don't want them in.
Finally if the max is a 2 it means than there is at least something that's not a pass or a fail in the status. If I understood your question correctly you want these too.

This is the query:

```
select empid, name
from
(
    select empid, name,
    max(if(status = 'pass', 0, if(status != 'fail', 2, 1))) as w
    from 
    emps
    group by empid
) t
where w != 1
```

*(Edited out previous answer)*

Comment: I can have more status like disburse,waiting etc.....but i mentioned only few status values.so I cant check only for pass status

Comment: if you want to include any other status for employees that have a fail row in the results just replace the 2 last checks with this a.status = 'fail' and b.status != 'fail' and this a.status != 'fail' and b.status = 'fail' . This way anything that's not just fails is included.

Comment: I am not getting the result what i excepted.The result should contain all the empids .if status fail exists delete the record from output except if the empid have status withdrawn or withhold or both.please help me.Thanks

Comment: i found a different approach that i believe should work for you. I edited the original answer.

Comment: Its not like check should be based on pass status.what ever the status except fail i should get all the distinct empid records.and also i should get empid if fail status for an empid exists with either withheld or withdrawn or both.I removed pass status for empid 11 but tht should exists in result table.

Comment: yes i think the new query i added returns what you just described.

Comment: yes.but is ther a way with out checking status = 'pass'.because i jst gave an example to satisfy my requirement.I dn't want to check with status pass as there are many status and i dont know what the status are except fail,withdrawn and withhold.please help me out.Thanks in advance

Comment: if withdrawn and withhold are the only ones in this category(meaning anything else other than fail is considered a pass) you can just change the if statement so you keep the same scores(passing statuses 0, fails 1, other 2). If on the other hand you don't know what status is considered a pass and you don't know what status is considered a withhold then you can't do it.

Comment: the passing status are all status(eg:withdrawn,withheld.disburse,onhold,waiting,pass etc.(They are many statuses))except fail and also fail record should exist if tht emp id have combination of either withdrawn,withheld or both.please tell me the query.Thanks

Comment: as told previously i added one more id 12 with status fail and disbure.this record should not exist but your query retrieves this record in the result table

Comment: what about this if statement if(status='withdrawn' or status='withheld', 2, (if status = 'fail', 1, 0))

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to assign a values to -1,1 and 1 to fail , withdrawn and withheld. Then sum them and only select records > 1

```
SELECT empid, 
       name 
FROM   employee 
GROUP  BY empid, 
          name 
HAVING Sum(CASE status 
             WHEN 'fail' THEN -1 
             WHEN 'withdrawn' THEN 1 
             WHEN 'withheld' THEN 1 
             ELSE 0 
           end) > -1
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/359cb/11)

Another more traditional approach uses IN and NOT IN clauses

```
SELECT DISTINCT empid, 
                name 
FROM   employee 
WHERE  empid NOT IN (SELECT empid 
                     FROM   employee 
                     WHERE  status = 'fail') 
        OR empid IN (SELECT empid 
                     FROM   employee 
                     WHERE  status IN ( 'withheld', 'withdrawn' ))
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/359cb/16)